# Are there permanent consequences for decisions in the campaign?

Tags: anno-2070

I've come to the first mission in the campaign (1-3) that has a decision you need to make, asking you to side either with the Ecos or the Tycoons for your development choices.

[image: anno]

Are there permanent ramifications for my decisions, like reputation gain/loss, tech tree access, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, or at least not there. i completed a good part of the campaign and i had other chances to choose a side and all the choices were only temporary.

Comment: So you don't even get extra reputation for the side you choose?